# How to use Thread in PHP on Windows

Tags: php, multithreading, installation

I want to use thread in PHP . I am using windows . What needs to be done to do this . Here is the code i am running .

```
<?php
class AsyncOperation extends Thread {
  public function __construct($arg){
    $this->arg = $arg;
  }

  public function run(){
    if($this->arg){
      printf("Hello %s\n", $this->arg);
    }
  }
}
$thread = new AsyncOperation("World");
if($thread->start())
  $thread->join();
?>
```

When i run the code it shows

Fatal error: Class 'Thread' not found in D:\xampp\htdocs\my.php on line 2

Thanks in advance

Comment: `Thread` is a PECL package - did you install it? http://pecl.php.net/package/pthreads

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like the pthreads extension is not installed on your system.
It's a custom PHP extension not by default installed with XAMPP.
Go fetch it.

You find pthread releases for Windows over at http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/

Add `pthreadVC2.dll` to the same directory as `php.exe`, e.g. `C:\xampp\php`
Add `php_pthreads.dll` to PHP extention folder, eg. `C:\xampp\php\ext`

Then modify `php.ini` by adding `extension=php_pthreads.dll` in the extensions section.

The code you posted is a basic example, which should work right out of the box, when the extension is installed.

---

And a goodie on top:
**[Video by Joe Watkins explaining "Parallel PHP"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HAZfDy6HTos)**

Comment: I just did what you told me to do . but still shows same error . Is there any other thing i need to install ? 
I am using XAMPP 5.6.3 and dowloaded php_pthreads-2.0.9-5.6-ts-vc11-x86.zip and pasted two specified files in the specific folder .

Comment: Yes. You need to modify php.ini - the extensions section and include php_ptreads.dll there. Just search for ".dll" in php.ini. and add it at the bottom.

Comment: thank you . solved the problem . Had to add "extension=php_pthreads.dll" to php.ini

Comment: I have the same problem but adding extension=php_pthreads.dll didn´t solve it