# How to get threads working in PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, multithreading, xampp, php-pthread

I want to run PHP Thread class code on Windows. I tried some manual installation guides like e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27823662/3764804) but they didn't work. PHP cannot load the pthreads DLL even though the file exists at this location:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_pthreads.dll' (tried: C:\xampp\php\ext\php_pthreads.dll (The specified module could not be found), C:\xampp\php\ext\php_php_pthreads.dll.dll (The specified module could not be found)) in Unknown on line 0
```

[I downloaded php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads/3.1.6/php_pthreads-3.1.6-7.0-ts-vc14-x64.zip). My PHP version is: `PHP 8.1.6 (cli) (built: May 11 2022 08:55:59) (ZTS Visual C++ 2019 x64)`. Generally I'm still not entirely sure which `pthread` version to select since there are many choices [here](https://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/pthreads). Are any of them even going to work since they seem a bit outdated? My `phpinfo` says:
[image]

Can I maybe just use Windows threads since they are already available on my system?

After the pthreads installation, when I run my Thread class example code

```
<?php

class AsyncOperation extends Thread
{
    public function __construct($arg)
    {
        $this->arg = $arg;
    }

    public function run()
    {
        if ($this->arg) {
            printf("Hello %s\n", $this->arg);
        }
    }
}

$thread = new AsyncOperation("World");
if ($thread->start())
    $thread->join();
?>
```

I still get the warning above and the following error:
`PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Thread" not found`

What am I doing wrong? Is there maybe a way to do it with less "manual" effort in e.g. 1 `composer` command or an easier way to get threading working?

Comment: Not sure what your use case is and if it will suffice, but have you looked at the [parallel](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.parallel.php) functionality?
I see you tried using phtreads, but it is deprecated in favor of parralel, see the [docs](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pthreads.php#:~:text=pthreads%20is%20an%20object%2Dorientated,Threads%2C%20Workers%20and%20Threaded%20objects.&text=This%20extension%20is%20considered%20unmaintained%20and%20dead.&text=Consider%20using%20parallel%20instead.).

Comment: Maybe this can help?
https://www.php.net/manual/en/pthreads.installation.php#115004